# How to allow only 1 role to have read access to an item?

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I want specific website users to have access to the "Secret" pages of the website.

I have created a new role in the Extranet domain i.e. `Extranet/SecretPageRole`.

Now, how do I assign roles for "secret" page item in Sitecore so that only users with Role `Extranet/SecretPageRole` should have access to it?

Currently, I have set the below Access permissions.
[image: Access]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Note: Currently the item does not have any descendants, but can have descendants in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Deny` access right always has the highest priority. You cannot revoke it with `Allow` access right later.

Set `Allow` access right for Item Read and Descendants Read for your role:

[image]

And for `extranet\everyone` break the inheritance on the item:

[image]

With that set, `extranet\everyone` will not have `Read` access, cause there won't be any rule which allows it. You can use Access Viewer app to check that:

[image]

Comment: Trying this out.

Comment: I have tried this and this works fine with the customRole. Sitecore automatically shifts the Extranet/Everyone Role to the top when added. The challenge now is extranet\Everyone doesn't seem to cover extranet\Anonymous user. The page is still accessible by extranet/Anonymous user without any role (still Debugging this)

Answer (score 0):

By putting the X in Everyone you are effectively adding an explicit deny to literally everyone, including SecretPageRole.
Not done it but if you can just remove the green tick from Everyone it will become an implicit deny and not affect inheriting roles.

Comment: I will try it out. Will create a new page with the configuration you mentioned and check if something happens to it.